# Flex spark to 'wear' button skin for dropdownlist component

Tags: apache-flex, custom-component, flex-spark, skin

I have a custom dropdownlist component (inherited from a previous project). I would like to 'wear' a button skin for this custom dropdownlist (The custom dropdownlist's behaviors are unchanged).

Is this possible and if possible, how can I implement this idea?

Best Regards,
HBLE

Comment: What does `'wear'` mean?

Comment: 'wear' means in appearance, it's a button component but inside (behaviors and parameters), it's still custom dropdownlist!

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. DropDownList already has a Button in its skin that covers the entire component. Or is your custom dropdownlist not a subclass of the Spark DropDownList? Perhaps some code or an image might help.